# Can a SharePoint WFE be added to a farm to host unique web applications that are not part of the existing 2013 farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Can a SharePoint WFE be added to a farm to host unique web applications that are not part of the existing farm?

We have a test farm which currently hosts our flagship product and other supporting web applications for testing. Can a 2nd WFE be added to the farm to host a distinct/unique separate version of one or more of those apps?

Our goal is to create an area where we can test upgraded versions of the integrated analytics product and support controls (eg- latest version of infragistics). The reason for the 2nd WFE is to have a different GAC for these products and our own to keep things segregated.

Any thoughts / comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do it, Because when you deploy a solution SharePoint automatically deploy to all servers in the farm.

I would recommend, as you have one server( WFE) go for single Server farm and do your testing. Here are [guide line for the sharepoint topology](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#hwforwebserver).